# IE Quirks Mode and CSS :hover Issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-selectors

Well, I've been racking my brain this afternoon and have not made any progress.  I am trying to do a simple background position change that I have done 100s of times but it just is not working for me today.  Here is my relevant code:

```
<div class="social_icon" style="background-image: url(http://img.deusm.com/lightreading/facebook_icon.gif);">
    <img src="http://img.deusm.com/images/spacer.gif" width="16" height="16" style="border: none; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
</div>
```

And my CSS

```
div.social_icon {
float: left; 
width: 16px; 
height: 16px;
padding: 0;
background-position: top left;
}
div.social_icon:hover {
background-position: bottom left;
}
```

I do have a doctype set as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated so that I can gain a better understanding of what is happening...er....not happening.

Let me clarify my question:

I am expecting the div.social_icon to have it's background position move when the user hovers over the element.  At this time, the background-position does not change on hover in Quirks Mode.  How can I fix that?

Comment: IE5.5 quirks mode quite simply does not support `:hover` on anything but `a` elements. There is nothing you can do except bail out of quirks mode using a proper doctype.

Comment: I am testing in IE7&8 Quirks Mode.  Is that much different than 5.5?

Comment: Not at all, they both act like IE5.5 in quirks mode.

Comment: Should I bother trying a JQuery-related solution or will this simply come down to the doctype?

Comment: You could, if you really must rely on quirks mode.

Comment: Hover doesn't work in quirks mode, but do you actually want to be in quirks mode? You have a doctype, which *should* be putting it into standards mode. If it isn't, you need to be asking why not, rather than asking how to cope with quirks mode.

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the top of your code it should sort it out but make sure you remove your current Doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Then after it should work